# What is the best method to apply a screen protector to a touchscreen?

Tags: iphone, ipad, touchscreen

Installing a screen protector on a touchscreen is not always easy.  Bubbles and dust can make your screen look horrible.  What is the best method/procedure you have found to apply a screen protector?

Answer (score 5):

First I make sure the screen is completely clean using a micro-fiber cloth, then I use a credit card with the cloth wrapped around to press the screen protector tightly as soon as it touches the screen.

The trick is to press, making a forward/backward movement, the protector against the screen as soon as it touches it, removing any bubbles in the process. So don't try to put the protector all at once.

Answer (score 3):

I live in a dry climate, so preventing dust from settling on the screen during application is one of the biggest concerns.  Another is in getting it aligned just right.  Here are some additional steps have used to get the absolute best results.

Note: this involves using water and electronics together, so you must be very careful to use the absolute minimum amount of water and the absolute maximum amount of care.  It could void your warranty, ruin your device, and/or inflict serious personal injury.  Perform at your own risk!

### Supplies

1. Unopened screen protector
2. A shower or bathroom you can steam up (dry/dusty climates)
3. Microfiber cloth (I like the 3M Microfiber dusting cloth I picked up at the Grocery store)
4. Canned air (just in case)
5. Fine mist water sprayer (the InvisiShield screen protectors from [Zagg](http://www.zagg.com/) come with a great sprayer filled with what I can only guess is distilled water)
6. Small squeegee or something like it (credit card, etc.)

### Procedure

1. Steam up your bathroom or shower by running very hot water in your shower.  This will help ensure airborne dust is minimized
2. Wash your hands throughly to remove oils from your fingerprints.
3. After you shut off the water, bring your supplies in.
4. Clean the screen using the microfiber cloth.  Inspect it carefully.  Use the canned air if necessary.  No dust should be visible at all.
5. Peel off the backing of your screen protector (don't touch the back, handle only with the sites)
6. Spray a very fine mist of water to the sticky side of the screen protector.  This will make it easier to align your screen protector precisely.
7. Position the screen protector at one end, using the squeegee lightly as you go to push out bubbles.  The water will form a thin film that makes it much easier to push out bubbles to the edge.
8. Once everything is in place and you have inspected for dust, use the squeegee and the microfiber cloth to push out bubbles and the thin water film to the edges.  Use the microfiber cloth to absorb water as it squirts out from under the protector, especially around buttons, case edgings, seams, and and other openings.
9. Sometimes, a small bit of water is trapped under the screen protector, but in my experience it goes away after a couple of days in a dry climate.